# is it healthy to run everyday at least 5 km when overweight?

Tags: running

I'm 180 cm and 94 kg and I run every day about 5 km with pace 5:00-5:30 min/km and on weekends I run 10+ km.

Is it healthy for my body in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Eric said it could be "healthier" than not doing anything at all.

**But**: Especially in the beginning of a running career, too many runs can lead to injury. Your muscles will probably do the job, but other stuff, like your sinews and cartilages just need more time to adapt to this unusual pressure.
It may seem fine in the beginning, but you may cause serious harm to your body.

> I'm 180 cm and 94 kg and I run every day about 5 km with pace 5:00-5:30 min/km and on weekends I run 10+ km.

It sounds as if you are already doing this routine for some time and it seems as if it didn't lead to injury so far. So maybe you are lucky. But what are your goals following this routine? If you want to lose weight it may be more usefull to change your diet and do some strength training.

If you want to get better at running, you should think about changing your routine, because it essential to allow your body some time for recovery to adapt in a way that improves your running. In addition running the same distance in the same pace is not a good thing to do, because you won't train your body to get faster or to run for longer distances. To achieve that you have to get a stimulus.

Maybe for the beginning you could start with a routine like this:

1. Day: Do a faster run for maybe about 6-8 km. You can get out of breath but shouldn't go all out.
2. Day: Do some intervalls. At your stage you could warm up an then do something like 4 intervalls of 800m with a "rest" phase of slower running between them. The pace should be set so fast, that the last intervall is really hard to finish.
3. Day: Do a long run. You can start with the 10km and increase the distance step by step. The pace should be slower than with the other runs. You should feel comfortable.

If you need the activity each day to calm down or something like that, you could think about doing some crosstraining, like biking or swimming, as these sports won't strain your body so much.

I hope the answer isn't to far from your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any knee pain caused by it, it's definitely healthier than not doing it.

I would advise adding some sort of resistance training to your routine in order to make sure that you mainly burn fat and not muscle.